# AKS autoscale not scaling up nodes when node(s) exceed max volume count

Tags: azure-aks

I have one AKS cluster having a nodepool with autoscaling enabled (min 3 max 6,type Standard_D16s_v3).
I have 133 pods and 97 PVC, one pods is in pending state. See events of pods below.
I have following affinity roles. I am expecting AKS auto scaler should scale nodes because pods are not getting scheduled.
Please suggest what i am missing here.

```
spec:                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│   affinity:                                                                                                                                                                              │
│     podAffinity:                                                                                                                                                                         │
│       requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:                                                                                                                                    │
│       - labelSelector:                                                                                                                                                                   │
│           matchLabels:                                                                                                                                                                   │
│             bp-app: app                                                                                                                                                      │
│         topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname                                                                                                                                              │
│     podAntiAffinity:                                                                                                                                                                     │
│       requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:                                                                                                                                    │
│       - labelSelector:                                                                                                                                                                   │
│           matchLabels:                                                                                                                                                                   │
│             bp-app: app                                                                                                                                                                │
│         topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname                                                                                                                                              │
│       - labelSelector:                                                                                                                                                                   │
│           matchLabels:                                                                                                                                                                   │
│             bp-app: app                                                                                                                                                                │
│         topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone 




    │   Type     Reason             Age                    From                Message                                                                                                         │
│   ----     ------             ----                   ----                -------                                                                                                         │
│   Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  27m (x26 over 64m)     cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity rules, 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/ant │
│ i-affinity rules                                                                                                                                                                         │
│   Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  2m13s (x346 over 67m)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity rules, 1 node(s) didn't match po │
│ d affinity rules                                                                                                                                                                         │
│   Warning  FailedScheduling   113s (x57 over 67m)    default-scheduler   0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) exceed max volume count.
```